# How to get Nginx to support the HTTP OPTIONS method

Tags: nginx, http

I have an Nginx server this is returning a 403 when a client uses the HTTP OPTIONS method. It sounds like Nginx does not support the OPTIONS method, but I couldn't find conclusive evidence of this on the Interwebs.

Right now Nginx is running on Centos5. Is it true that Nginx does not support this and is there a module that could be enabled for Nginx to support OPTIONS?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is not supported in nginx. Your options are to write a module yourself, or wait for someone else to do it. There is a list of [official modules](http://wiki.nginx.org/Modules) and [3rd party modules](http://wiki.nginx.org/3rdPartyModules) available on their wiki.

Answer (score 1):

Nginx does indeed support the OPTIONS method.  It is specifically mentioned in the documentation for the core module:

http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_core_module.html#limit_except

You can configure nginx to respond to it on the basis of the value of the `$request_method` variable.